# Return a document with the largest value

Tags: couchdb

I've got a series of documents that have a version field.

```
{
 "_id": "xxx",
 "_rev": "6-4bdeb530234c454ae2f16d77ba577428",
 "name": "glossary",
 "locale": "en-us",
 "version": "186.0",
 "title": "Glossary",
 ...
}
```

I'd like to be able to return the document where name is glossary that has the largest version.

If I make the map function like this:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.name, doc);
  }
```

and do a reduce on it, I can figure out which document has the latest version, but when I try to return it (`return latest_doc`), I get a `reduce_overflow_error` error.

It seems like I need to do this via a map function only, but I can't figure out how to return a single document with the highest value from the map.

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Can you help me get the latest version of my glossary document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce_overflow_error` is couchdb's way of telling you that you are not using reduce in a way it is supposed to be used. From the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Reduce_Functions)

> Reduce is a powerful feature of CouchDB but is often misused which leads to performance problems. From 0.10 onwards, CouchDB uses a heuristic to detect reduce functions that won't scale to give the developer an early warning. A reduce function must reduce the input values to a smaller output value. If you are building a composite return structure in your reduce, or only transforming the values field, rather than summarizing it, you might be misusing this feature

Try this map function

```
function(doc) {
 emit([doc.name,doc.version], doc._id);
```

}

query it with

`/view-name?include_docs=true&startkey=["glossary",{}]&endkey=["glossary"]&descending=true&limit=1`

This will give you the the file with the highest version number. Remove the `limit` parameter if you want more files.